# XML to HTML not showing anything

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm trying to parse an XML in a server and getting that XML's element image URL and then showing it into my document. And to be sure Im also putting some condition where if XML isn't parsed then alert me, but its not alerting me since the parsing is a success. The problem is im not getting anything when load the function.

```
var xmlDoc = Obj.responseXML;
    if(xmlDoc){
        var count = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item").lenght;
        for(var i = 0; i <= count; i++){
            document.getElementById("flow").innerHTML += "<div class='item'> <img class='content' src='" + xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("icon")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue.replace(/\s+$/g,' ') +"' /></div>";     
        };
    } else {

        alert("Parse Not Successfull!");
    }
```

my HTML looks like this,

```
<div id="coverFlow">
            <div class="flow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var count = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item").lenght;
                                                ^^^^^^
                                                length
                                                    ^^
```

and the other issue id!=class

```
document.getElementById("flow")
                     ^^

<div class="flow"></div>
     ^^^^^
```

Comment: that's a bummer for my spelling. :) and btw im getting this error TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("flow").innerHTML')  any idea.

Comment: Where is the id with flow? This is not an id `class="flow"`?